# Symfony: Opposite Of An Inner Join Query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Seeking to duplicate this SQL query using Symfony's createQueryBuilder:

```
Select * from user
left join location on location.id = user.id
where location.id is null
```

Have tried:

```
$er->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->leftJoin('u.location','l')
    ->where('l.id = :id ')
    ->setParameter('id',null);
```

Entities - User,Location. User has OneToMany relationship with Locations.

QueryBuilder generated SQL

```
SELECT u0_.id AS id0, u0_.firstname AS firstname1, u0_.lastname AS lastname2, u0_.creationDate AS creationDate3 
FROM User u0_ 
LEFT JOIN Locations l1_ ON u0_.id = l1_.user_id 
WHERE l1_.id = ? 
ORDER BY u0_.firstname AS
```

Comment: Are you supposed to define which table you're reading from?
->from('User', 'u')

Comment: 'u' is alias for User.

Comment: Looks like generated query is good. Probably problem is with passing 'null' as parameter's value

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. Changed how `id` was checked if it is a null.

```
$qBuilder = $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
             ->leftJoin('u.locations','l')
             ->where('l.id is NULL');
```

Hope it will help someone.